# contract to trade Usdt To Dai ON n on sushiswap on kovan testneT keeps failing

Tags: ethereum, solidity

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.7.0; 






 contract unisimple {
  event unirouterAddress(address);
  event suishirouterAddress(address);
       using SafeMath for uint256; 
       address immutable factory;
       
       IUniswapV2Router01  public immutable  sushirouter ; 
 
    // IERC20 public TOKEN0_ERC20;
      uint deadline;
  
  //IERC20 public TOKEN1_ERC20;


    constructor(address _factory,IUniswapV2Router01 sushirouter_ ) public {
       factory = _factory;  
         sushirouter  =    IUniswapV2Router01(address(sushirouter_));
         emit suishirouterAddress(address(sushirouter_));
        deadline = block.timestamp + 300; 

    }  // constructor

    function arbitrage(address tokenin , address tokenout, uint Tradeamount) public {
        address[] memory  path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = tokenin ;
        path[1] =  tokenout ; 
       
        IERC20 TOKEN0_ERC20 = IERC20(tokenin); // ierc20 instance of the contract
     
        TOKEN0_ERC20.approve(address(sushirouter),Tradeamount); 

uint amountRequired = sushirouter.getAmounsIn(Tradeamount, path)[0]; =
sushirouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(Tradeamount,  amountRequired  , path, address(this), deadline ); /*  interacting with router to trade tokens in paths */

    }

    }
```

the code above doesn'twork
although it does deploy to the kovan testnet
not sure why though . Really need help with this , cant seem to make this work . This would be extremely appreciated .

Comment: These are the imports that i used .   
    import './libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol';
    import  "./Constants.sol";
    import '@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/libraries/SafeMath.sol';
    import { ILendingPool, ILendingPoolAddressesProvider, IERC20 } from "./Interfaces.sol";
    import "./interfaces/IUniswapV2Router01.sol";
    import '@uniswap/lib/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol';

Comment: imports were added  however i left them out because the  stackoverflow . But the imports work and the router contract  has indeed been initiated

Comment: What values do you use in the constructor for `_factory` and `sushirouter_`?

Comment: so I used the kovan testnet  addressess of  sushiswap .  which is 
sushirouter_1 = '0x1b02dA8Cb0d097eB8D57A175b88c7D8b47997506'; and

Comment: also the  i used the factory addressess sushiswap_factory = '0xc35DADB65012eC5796536bD9864eD8773aBc74C4';